# With Dexie, can I get all objects in a table where an array field has a specific value as one of its elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, field, indexeddb, dexie

I have a table where each object has a field that is an array of strings:  for example, `{ people: ['John', 'Bob', 'Sue'] }`.  I need all objects in the table that have 'Sue' in the `people` array.

Can Dexie do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using [MultiEntry](https://dexie.org/docs/MultiEntry-Index) indexes you can do exactly that.

```js
const db = new Dexie("testdb");
db.version(2).stores({
  groups: 'id, *people'
});

async function addRow() {
  await db.groups.add({id: 1, people: ['John', 'Bob', 'Sue']});
}

async function findSuesGroups() (
  return await db.groups.where('people').equals('Sue').toArray();
}
```

See other examples at https://dexie.org/docs/MultiEntry-Index

Comment: how can I read the same if it's not a string but an object inside array??? in findSuesGroups method